# What does ".local" do?

Tags: networking, dns, hostname

I've got several Ubuntu machines on my network at home, but the DNS is provided by a windows server (2K).  When I ssh to them from another , if I ssh to them as "machine" I can't connect, but if I connect as "machine.local" I can connect.

I think similarly, I can't connect from a windows client (like putty).

What's going on here? - it's clearly an Ubuntu thing.

Comment: Actually, it looks like a DNS thing, not like an Ubuntu thing at all (especially since you “can't connect” from the Windows machine — and what is the error message anyway?). What is your DNS configuration (`nameserver` *and* `search`)? How does `dig machine1` differ from `dig machine1.local`?

Comment: Would you happen to have Apple Bonjour or another Zeroconf implementation installed on the Windows 2000 Server?

Comment: If you happen to know why Android can't browse to a device on the network using its .local hostname (https://devicename.local does *not* work but it *can* browse to https://devicename without .local), I'd appreciate an answer at https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230644/22600 Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

By default, Ubuntu includes avahi. This is an implementation of zeroconf which allows computer hostnames to be resolved with the virtual ".local" name. Whenever your computer tries to connect to "hostname.local", avahi will perform local network broadcasts to see if there any computers with that hostname. Other computers running avahi (or something compatible) should answer.

If you look in /etc/nsswitch.conf, you will find the following line:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

The mdns4_minimal is the configuration setting that makes this redirection work.

Your question actually suggests that avahi is running successfully as you say that you can connect to your Ubuntu computers using "hostname.local". However, you do not make it clear ("When I ssh to them from another, ...") if you are trying to connect from another Ubuntu computer, or from another Windows computer. Without installing other software such as Bonjour, Windows computers cannot resolve zeroconf-style "hostname.local" names.

Comment: [Avahi Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29) for the interested.  In short, its complicated.

Comment: This answer is rather old now, but Windows 10 will definitely resolve "hostname.local" style names without anything extra (at least... no third-party extras... who knows what garbage is running internally)

Answer (score 15):

To fix your issue, you just need Avahi. This announces your Ubuntu machine names to the Windows lot.

```
sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon
```

`machinename.local` works thanks to another implementation of zeroconf (of which Avahi is also) called Bonjour, created (IIRC) by Apple. It's installed by default. I don't know why Avahi isn't also but given the confusion it causes people, it probably aught to be.

There's more on this on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local

Comment: Avahi uses .lan I think

Comment: No, avahi uses `.local`, this is required by the mDNS spec.

Comment: Why would you expect macOS to install multiple zeroconf implementations? I don't see what confusion the existence of Bonjour and Avahi could cause any remotely reasonable person. I'm not trying to be combative, I'm just honestly baffled by what you're saying. AFAI can tell, what you're saying is like saying "Finder is installed by default on macOS. I don't know why explorer.exe isn't also given the confusion it causes people".

Comment: @MarcelBesixdouze I didn't air any expectation of OS X (as it was still called 12 years ago). I was suggesting Ubuntu should have something I thought it didn't have.