# Unable to ssh into server using hostname

Tags: ssh, 22.04

I am new to Ubuntu and recently tried to ssh into my raspberry pi. I get the error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname microwave:
Temporary failure in name resolution.
```

The server and the host both use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)

Comment: Why are you using a hostname to ssh within a local network? This isn't going to work unless you have a local DNS server that defines that host name with the IP address. What happens when you use the IP address? Is the IP address for the pi reserved on your home network?

Comment: It is reserved but I have to disable the random mac address for it to actually be assigned said reserved IP address, and I use the hostname just in case I forget the IP address.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [18.04 does not resolve hosts on local network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043907/18-04-does-not-resolve-hosts-on-local-network)

Comment: I believe for the RPi for a static MAC address you need to add `smsc95xx.macaddr = XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` to `/boot/cmdline.txt` file on the RPi itself.  Make sure to change the `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` to any MAC address that won't conflict with anything else on your network.

Comment: local names are working again on 22.04 for me.  Used to be a struggle under 20.04, needing the nsswitch package to make it work, but the systemd resolve seems to have successfully encompassed the feature. I've done nothing with DNS other than connect to my router. The .local works too.  Search dmesg for the reason for the temporary failure.  Used to be a fallback to UDP under certain circumstances.